# Page URL redirects in IIS

Tags: asp.net, url, iis, url-rewriting, response.redirect

in need my client to load a web page(www.secondsite.com/Page1.aspx) if  the request comes only from www.firstsite.com/Login.aspx.

other wise client the client should be redirected back to 
 www.secondsite.com/page1.aspx

can i achieve this using IIS 7 or any other way?. i have tried URL rewriting module in IIS and i have only managed to restrict the access to www.firstsite.com/Login.aspx and redirect thr request to www.firstsite.com/Login.aspx. but unable to achieve the above behavior in IIS. please help

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, see the [explanation here](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpredirect)